# How to use Apache solr with java

Tags: solr

I am having large amount of data in my database.I want to find the data with specific keyword.If i search the database using specific keyword it should return all the records containing that particular keyword.can any one help me regarding this problem?I am new to apache solr

Comment: I didnt tried anything i am asking how to search millions of records

Comment: try before asking in SO , thanks ( p.s. millions of records are not too many, as long as they are well-indexed )

Comment: I am not going to do all the work for you but you have a few options. Look at full text index search on your table, not sure what database your are using, look at lucene which powers solr and look at some hosted solutions for elasticsearch..

Comment: Can you send me some links useful for indexing

Comment: I am new to all these things.Work given to me is i have collection of documents which may be even in terabites also.I have to search for a particular word in the documents and i have to fetch the docs which are having that keyword

Answer (score 0):

DataImportHandler might help you.

http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DataImportHandler

But, this would also mean you need to configure your schema.xml accordingly as per your search requirements, i.e., 
1.  what fields needs to be searched/stored.
2.  what fields need to be processed(tokenization/filteration etc)

Quick way to go ahead would be to map your DB fields with specific types with your Index fields and SOLR's type and use DIH to index.

Best